# “Use one-click single sign-on” our implmentation not accepted by Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

**Google Market placed  refused our app integration with OAthu2 API for single sign on and we are in grace period for 15 days anyone could support**

Here 's our Implantation:

First we put button that call java-script function that send authentication request:

with following parameters:

```
   a- scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
   b- client_id= ###.apps.googleusercontent.com
   c- redirect_uri=https://www.domain.com/oauth2callback
   d- response_type=code
   e- state= "googletest"
```

Second we get the authorized code  so we follow step exchange the code to get  access token:

With following parameters:

```
        a- code  => retrieved code from the previous request,
        b- client_id  => our client id
        c- client_secret =>our client secret
        d- redirect_uri => our redirect uri
        e- grant_type => 'authorization_code'
```

Third  after we get the token from the response, we use the it to get  user directory contacts data.

through using the following URL:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?&alt=json&max-results=' .10 . '&oauth_token=' . token

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have published on google app market place i am not applying their standard correctly? so I want to know what i am missing

Comment: Details about the problem with your application should have been included in the email you got.